# Hard drive capacity on Windows server 2008 r2 not fully recognized

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2008-r2, storage

I am running Server 2008 release 2. I am almost out of hard drive space on the c partition. It is a 40 gig partition that is reporting 2.3 gig of free space. When I examine the properties of each folder size on this partition it adds up to about 28 gigs of used space. I can't determine why 10 gigs of capacity is not being recognized.  This system is using a PERC H700 raid adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to add up individual items be sure to account for hidden objects.  Your swap file (pagefile.sys) is hidden and will consume a considerable amount of disk space.  In **Folder Options** check the option to show hidden files, folders, and drives.